# How to get googlesheets to ignore blank rows in chart

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with multiple rows of data I am trying to put into a pie chart.  The problem is that it reports on blank values as a separate category (not really blank though, they are set to "" as a result of a formula).  Is there a way to suppress these blanks?

Answer (score 28):

Since I had the same issue, here how to solve it (at least for line charts):

Double click on the chart so the `Chart editor` opens. In the tab `Customize` open `Chart style` and check the checkbox `Plot null values`.

Thats it, now empty lines / cells will be ignored and the line will be plotted to the next existing value.

Answer (score 7):

It's best to not put "" in cells in the first place; the presence of such kind-of-empty-but-not-really cells leads to some issues that can be difficult to debug. To avoid such cells, don't use `if(A1=1, 2, "")` and similar; use `if(A1=1, 2, )` instead, leaving the third argument truly blank.

But if you already have a range with some entries like that, you can use a formula like

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A1:B), A1:B, ))
```

to clean it up. This leaves most entries unchanged, except that "" will be replaced by blank cells.

Comment: This does not answer the question? While it gives information on good practice, it doesn't say anything about how you solve his problem, which is that the blank cells show up in the pie chart. Can you elaborate on how to solve this issue, as I am having the same problem? It doesn't matter if the cell is "" or blank (null?), it still happens.

Comment: It might be a good idea, but not sure how it helps. It does not solve this particular problem.